# How to use simanneal package

Tags: python-3.x, simulated-annealing

I am trying to optimize parameters of my function/object, using simulated annealing via the simanneal package https://github.com/perrygeo/simanneal .
My code looks as follows:

```
from simanneal import Annealer

class ReservoirAnnealer(Annealer):

    def __init__(self, state, res):
        self.reservoir = res
        self.resSize = np.size(self.reservoir.W_top)
        super(ReservoirAnnealer, self).__init__(state) 


    def move(self):
        a = random.randint(0, self.resSize)
        b = random.randint(0, self.resSize)
        self.state[a,b] ^= 1

    def energy(self):
        reservoir.W = self.state
        return reservoir.fit(data, 1500, penalty=5e-7, errorEvaluationLength=750)

reservoir = Reservoir(1,1023,spectralRadius=1.25,inputScaling=1,leakingRate=0.3, transientTime=100)
initialState = reservoir.W_top.ravel()
annealer = ReservoirAnnealer(initialState, reservoir)
```

W_top is a matrix with either 0 or 1 inside, so something like this:

```
[ 1.  1.  1. ...,  0.  0.  1.]
```

When I execute the code from above, I am getting the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-5a5b9eb8c324> in <module>()
     20 reservoir = Reservoir(1,1023,spectralRadius=1.25,inputScaling=1,leakingRate=0.3, transientTime=100)
     21 initialState = reservoir.W_top.ravel()
---> 22 annealer = ReservoirAnnealer(initialState, reservoir)
     23 #itinearay, cost = annealer.anneal()

<ipython-input-87-5a5b9eb8c324> in __init__(self, state, res)
      6         self.reservoir = res
      7         #self.resSize = np.size(self.reservoir.W)
----> 8         super(ReservoirAnnealer, self).__init__(state)
      9 
     10 

C:\Users\Luca\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simanneal\anneal.py in __init__(self, initial_state, load_state)
     45 
     46     def __init__(self, initial_state=None, load_state=None):
---> 47         if initial_state:
     48             self.state = self.copy_state(initial_state)
     49         elif load_state:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I dont really know, what that means though. The original example works with an dictionary, but my matrix is pretty big, and I dont want to put that in a dictionary.
Does anybody know how to use the library correctly?

Comment: full traceback?

Comment: try and pass a list into it instead (the init function - thats why its failing anyway the if statement on the numpy array)

Comment: Oh thanks, that worked

Comment: np, given that it worked i am emboldened to add an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a list into it. It is failing due to the if statement on the numpy array @ line anneal: 47